# Can't access property if object is taken from array

Tags: javascript

This outputs "value", while with the commented out line it is "undefined". Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

function Obj(property) {
    this.property = property;
}

var arr = [new Obj("value")]
var obj = new Obj("value");
//var obj = arr.splice(0, 1);
console.log(obj.property);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because splice returns an array of the deleted elements. Try `obj[0].property`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `splice()` returns an array of elements:

```
console.log(obj[0].property);
```

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) *(I've bolded the significant part that pertains to your example)*:

> An array containing the deleted elements. **If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned**. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

#### Working Example

```
function Obj(property) {
    this.property = property;
}

var arr = [new Obj("value")]
var obj = arr.splice(0, 1);
console.log(obj[0].property);
// "value"
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because splice returns extracted array based on the parameters given, so obj becomes an array containing an element. so you must use 
console.log(obj[0].property);

Answer (score 0):

[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function returns an array with *spliced items*. so access the property you should do:

```
var obj = arr.splice(0, 1)[0]; // extract the object first
console.log(obj.property);
```

OR

```
var obj = arr.splice(0, 1);
console.log(obj[0].property);
```

OR

```
var obj = arr[0];
console.log(obj.property);
```